# React-Native app reloads instead of resuming the last screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

React-Native version: 0.58.6

Sometimes my app (on both ios and android) resumes the last screen I was on before pressing the home button, but in most cases I witness a complete app reload starting with a SplashScreen.

Why does the reload happen? Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: you shoud really provide a code sample, most likely there is a bug in your code regarding navigation events.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/7zedb7/android_react_native_app_restarts_from_initial/